# Is there a way to make svg.js work with node.js

Tags: node.js, jsdom, svg.js

Did someone of you try to make svg.js work with node.js? I tried to use the jsdom module to render svg but jsdom but SVG.supported returns false. Is there a way to make this library work with node.js?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** Here is my code, I want to make that on Node.js and then probably render the SVG in a pdf or as a png:

```
var draw = SVG('drawing').size(600, 600) 
var image = draw.image('inclusions.png') 
image.size(400, 150) 
var rect = draw.rect(400, 150).attr({ fill: 'orange' }) 
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 
    var point = draw.circle(5) 
    var xpos = Math.floor((Math.random() * 400) + 1); 
    var ypos = Math.floor((Math.random() * 150) + 1); 
    point.x(xpos) 
    point.y(ypos) 
    point.fill('black') 
} 
image.front()
```

Comment: What specifically are you trying to do? Are you trying to render SVG in order to display it to the screen somehow? Or are you trying to save the render to a file? Could you provide a sample bit of code that illustrates, from start to finish, what you would like to do?

Comment: Add your code as an edit to the post (click the edit link on the bottom left of your post).

Comment: Do you only need to do this operation once, or does it need to be automatically generated at the request of an end user? How will the image be used?

Comment: It needs to be automatically generated everytime an end user makes a request

Answer (score 3):

Here is the working example usage of svg.js inside nodejs project,
[svgdom](https://github.com/svgdotjs/svgdom) is the suggested library from [svg.js official website](https://svgjs.dev/docs/3.0/faq/#can-svg-js-run-on-node-js)

```
const window = require('svgdom');
const SVG = require('svg.js')(window);
const document = window.document;

function generateSVGTextLines(width, height, lineList, tAsset) {
  var draw = SVG(document.documentElement).size(width, height);
  draw.clear();

  draw.text(function (add) {
    if (lineList) {
        for (var i = 0; i < lineList.length; i++) {
            add.tspan(lineList[i].text).attr("x", "50%").newLine();
        }
    }
  }).font({
    family: tAsset.fontFamily,
    size: tAsset.fontHeight,
    leading: '1.2em',
    anchor: "middle"
   }).move(width / 2, 0);

   return draw.svg();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This link might be helpful: http://techslides.com/save-svg-as-an-image

This documents a client side solution that causes the requisite SVG to be drawn on the end user's browser, rather than on the server, but it provides the end result you want by putting the SVG into an image tag and allowing the user to download it. If keeping the SVG drawing logic secret is a problem, you could use a similar principle by sicing [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) on the generator page and sending the user the image it downloads.

Comment: I need to make it run on server side. I managed to make my code work on PhantomJS but it really needs to work on Node.js server because the PhantomJS web server is not suitable for production

Comment: Is it possible for you to download PhantomJS onto the server as an offline program and start it in Node using `process.start()`? (You might not if you're using Heroku or similar).

Comment: I also made it work using PhantomJS in Node.js but it's not an optimal solution because the PhantomJS starts a new instance of the browser at every request

Comment: Which may not actually be that bad. [This article](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/05/love-generating-svg-javascript-move-to-server/) has a sample JSDom solution but claims that invoking a new instance of PhantomJS is actually faster. You don't know what will truly bottleneck your application until you actually profile and time each step.